# load access log file into dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I need to process a access log file and work on that.
Is it posible to load a log file like access log into a data frame and work on that.
I have a time stamp, response time and request url which I would like to work on.

example log line:

```
128.0.0.2 xml12.jantzens.dk - - [04/Mar/2013:07:59:29 +0100] 15625 "POST /servlet/XMLHandler HTTP/1.1" 200 516 "-" "dk.product.xml.client.transports.ServletBridge" "-"
```

Update: 
I am extracting the response time and request using regular exp. 
So I am trying to create a dataset by adding DF.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'time' : pd.Timestamp(timestamp),
                     'reponsetime' : responsetime,
                     'requesturl' : requesturl })
```

Comment: Please provide requested output for the input sample.

Comment: It should be possible. You will mostly likely get a better response on SO if you at least come up with and try your own approach at parsing the file and placing the required fields into a data frame. At that stage, post the relevant code and describe the problems you face (if you cannot get it to work). In other words, be prepared to answer ["What have you tried?"](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ "no try no answer")

Comment: I have tried looking through the documentation and havn't been able to find a way to do it.

Comment: In response to the updated question: if you are able to extract the necessary components from the lines in the log file, there are several ways to put them into a `DataFrame`. For example, you can create a list of dicts, with elements like the one you are passing to `DataFrame` in the code above. After that you can convert the entire list into a `DataFrame` as described [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#from-a-list-of-dicts). Other examples on that same page show other methods.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using regular expressions and loading the data into some type of in memory structure (I assume this is what you mean by data frame).

I love using Kodos to develop regular expressions: http://kodos.sourceforge.net/

For the log snippet you provide above, the following regular expressions will isolate some of the important parts:

```
^(?P<host>[0-9.a-zA-Z ]+)\s-\s-\s\[(?P<day>[0-9]{2})/(?P<month>[a-zA-Z]{3})/(?P<timestamp>[0-9:]+ \+[0-9]{4})]\s+[0-9]+\s+"([a-zA-Z0-9 /.']+)"\s+([0-9]{3})\s+([0-9]{3})\s+"([a-zA-Z0-9 /.-]+)"\s+"([a-zA-Z0-9 /.-]+)"\s+"([a-zA-Z0-9 /.-]+)"
```

Kodos creates some helpful code snippets too:

```
rawstr = r"""^(?P<host>[0-9.a-zA-Z ]+)\s-\s-\s\[(?P<day>[0-9]{2})/(?P<month>[a-zA-Z]{3})/(?P<timestamp>[0-9:]+ \+[0-9]{4})]\s+[0-9]+\s+"([a-zA-Z0-9 /.']+)"\s+([0-9]{3})\s+([0-9]{3})\s+"([a-zA-Z0-9 /.-]+)"\s+"([a-zA-Z0-9 /.-]+)"\s+"([a-zA-Z0-9 /.-]+)""""
embedded_rawstr = r"""^(?P<host>[0-9.a-zA-Z ]+)\s-\s-\s\[(?P<day>[0-9]{2})/(?P<month>[a-zA-Z]{3})/(?P<timestamp>[0-9:]+ \+[0-9]{4})]\s+[0-9]+\s+"([a-zA-Z0-9 /.']+)"\s+([0-9]{3})\s+([0-9]{3})\s+"([a-zA-Z0-9 /.-]+)"\s+"([a-zA-Z0-9 /.-]+)"\s+"([a-zA-Z0-9 /.-]+)""""
matchstr = """128.0.0.2 xml12.jantzens.dk - - [04/Mar/2013:07:59:29 +0100] 15625 "POST /servlet/XMLHandler HTTP/1.1" 200 516 "-" "dk.product.xml.client.transports.ServletBridge" "-""""

# method 1: using a compile object
compile_obj = re.compile(rawstr)
match_obj = compile_obj.search(matchstr)

# method 2: using search function (w/ external flags)
match_obj = re.search(rawstr, matchstr)

# method 3: using search function (w/ embedded flags)
match_obj = re.search(embedded_rawstr, matchstr)

# Retrieve group(s) from match_obj
all_groups = match_obj.groups()

# Retrieve group(s) by index
group_1 = match_obj.group(1)
group_2 = match_obj.group(2)
group_3 = match_obj.group(3)
group_4 = match_obj.group(4)
group_5 = match_obj.group(5)
group_6 = match_obj.group(6)
group_7 = match_obj.group(7)
group_8 = match_obj.group(8)
group_9 = match_obj.group(9)
group_10 = match_obj.group(10)

# Retrieve group(s) by name
host = match_obj.group('host')
day = match_obj.group('day')
month = match_obj.group('month')
timestamp = match_obj.group('timestamp')
```

You can build on that pretty easily to load the log into memory and start processing.

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:pandas]. The OP meant a [Pandas DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#dataframe).